# C# сколько ЦП используется по имени службы, например, в диспетчере задач

Tags: c#, .net, cpu

Я хотел бы знать, как получить использование ЦП в % моего приложения .net и отобразить его в консоли. Я знаю, как получить общий процессор, но мне нужно использовать только% использования процессора конкретным приложением.
Конечно мне нужно

```
using System.Diagnostics;
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess(); //Получение процесса
double mem = (double)(proc.WorkingSet64 / 1024 / 1024); //Получение используемой памяти в МБ
PerformanceCounter ram = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", proc.ProcessName); //Получение счётчика
Console.WriteLine("proc: " + ram.NextValue() + ", mem:" + mem); //Вывод
```